# Multiplication Table in C#

Tags: c#

Im new to C# (and programming in general) and im stuck on a School Lab.
Been trying to make the multiplication table 1-10 but I get an error I dont understand.

I got this using System.Array;   using System.Linq; aswell so what am I doing wrong? I might be doing nothing right hehe

```
 static void Calculate(int[] numbers)
    {
        int[] CalculateMultTable = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        Calculate(CalculateMultTable);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *What* is the error?

Comment: Also, it would help if you included the entire function - you're missing some closing braces for sure, makes me wonder if there's more.

Comment: My guess would be a `StackOverflowException`, since that method seems to have a bad case of _infinite recursion_.

Comment: I see 3 things wrong right off the bat (including misspelling `Length`), but you should put some more effort into your question. Tell us what you expect your output to be (and how you want to store and display it for example), What error message you are getting and what you tried to do to overcome it. You know, to make us feel like we are helping instead of doing your homework for you.

Comment: Why is this tagged `linq`?  I see no use of `linq` in the example code, and adding that will make this harder.

Comment: No need to crush this guy. He's brand new here, and he's a new programmer. It's a lot of cognitive load.

Comment: To the left of the line numbers is a grey area.  Find the line where you declare CalculateMultTable.  Click in the grey area.  You've made a breakpoint!  Now hit F5.  Now you're debugging!  Now hit F11.  Now you're stepping through code!  You should be able to figure out a lot of the small stuff now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers point out, you are making an infinite recursive call and are probably getting a `StackOverflowException`.  Also, I can't tell what you are doing with your array.  Are you supposed to be assigning into it?  Is it there just to help the loop print the right numbers?  You can do it simply this way:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
   {
      Console.Write((i * j).ToString() + "\t");
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

That will give you this as output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

If you want to save that into a 2D array, you can get rid of my `Console.WriteLine` and replace the `Console.Write` with code that looks like this:

```
int[,] multTable = new int[10,10];
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
   {
      multTable[i - 1, j - 1] = i * j;
   }
}
```

You probably want to change the return type of your method from `void` to `int[,]`, which is a two dimensional array of `int`s.

Even though I think you're going to throw it away, just as a tip to help save you some typing in the future, your array can be initialized much more easily than typing out all 10 elements.  When it follows a regular pattern like that, you can just use a loop:

```
int[] x = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   x[i] = i + 1;
}
//this will give you the same array.  
//Doesn't save any typing for just 10 elements, but saves a ton if you need,
//for example, 100 elements from 1-100
```

Comment: That's a good answer! I hope he tries to absorb it and doesn't just copy the answer into this homework.

Comment: @BrianMacKay that is why I didn't post the code for the return type, formatting nice row and column numbers, or how to print directly from the 2d array.  They still have a little bit of work in order to get this to work in their assignment (I hope).

Comment: Thank you for the Answear! People are really helpfull here! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Calculate(int[] numbers)
    {
        int[] CalculateMultTable = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        Calculate(CalculateMultTable);
        ...
```

Your code will never work, this is a recursive loop and there is no condition to escape from it.
Change the cose as follow and will works:

```
static void Calculate(int[] numbers)
{
    var CalculateMultTable = new int[10] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            numbers[i] = numbers[i]*numbers[i];
        //Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an infinite loop with that call to Calculate(CalculateMultTable), probably creating a StackOverflow exception. The function will call itself until you run out of memory.

If you remove that line, it will work, but it will only create entries where both sides of the multiplication are the same. For instance, 1 * 1, 2 * 2, * 3 * 3, and so on. I hope that was your intention.

```
static void Calculate(int[] numbers)
{
    int[] CalculateMultTable = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a one dimensional array which he overwrites. (wrongly, of course)

Comment: @SteelSoul  Arrays are reference types, so it may be working for him, although it wouldn't be my stylistic choice. Didn't want to confuse a newb more than necessary. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned a LINQ based solution :)

And apparently I couldn't find any google result for my search of such a one so I came up of the following code, which I hope will be useful to others as well:

```
var n = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var m = n.Select( n1 => n.Select(n2 => n1 * n2 ).ToArray() ).ToArray();

var result_will_be_10 = m[2][5];
var result_will_be_56 = m[8][7];
var result_will_be_81 = m[9][9];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] CalculateMultTable = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    int[][] table = new int[10][];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        table[i] = new int[10];
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j ++)
        {

            table[i][j] = CalculateMultTable[j] * (i + 1);
        }

    }
```

Just initialize a 1D array with 1,2,3....
in two for loops just do simple multiplication of value at `CalculateMultTable` index with the row number.